# Stop scrolling scrollbar automatically while adding Images in winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scrollbars

I have a thumbnail control where I am adding Images using openfiledialog and after adding it automatically scrolls down.

So I would like to stop scrolling the scrollbar and just append the Images.

I have tried using this code:

```
Thumbcontrol1.VerticalScroll.Value=0
```

It worked fine but the scrollbar is at the bottom and it shows me the first row of Images.

And this is my second attempt by doing this way:

I have just set the `autoscroll` `property` to `false` and it hides the scrollbars and I'm stuck with this so how do I scroll the remaining Images?

And Is there any other method to hide scrollbars and just scroll the Images using mouse? Or any other simpler way to get rid of this?

Comment: Pretty unclear.  You control the scroll position by assigning the AutoScrollPosition property.  Beware that it is negative.

Comment: @Hans Passant-Thanks for your reply and as component_tech said I have just set it's property to false before adding and reset it to true worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try setting autoscroll to false before adding an image, then setting it back to true after the image has been added.